# Parental gate in Admob Banner iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

Is there any way to handle click on admob banner view? I have game for kids, so I've added parental gate in in-app purchases as well as in chartboost using their age gate. I'm looking for the same solution for admob banner (interstitial could be as well).

I've tried adding delegate and indeed:

```
- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(nonnull GADBannerView *)bannerView {
    NSLog(@"adViewWillPresentScreen");
}
```

is called, but I can't find a way to intercept this flow and show parental gate, before it'll open an url or cancel it when user failed to solve parental gate.

I've also tried handling it in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);

    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

But when I'm clicking the banner it's not called.

In chartboost there's Age Gate:

```
- (void)didPauseClickForConfirmation {

    [AppDelegate showParentalGate:^(BOOL passed) {
        [Chartboost didPassAgeGate:passed];
    }];

}
```

Is there anything like this for admob? How can I do this?

Comment: answer is no. One of my app was rejected by apple for not having parental control. Admob doesn't allow you to handle click ( makes sense - for not allowing intential clicks ). Itunes technical team recommended to release new app, as previous app was already approved for children usage

Comment: here is solution provided by google as alternative but havn't tried it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/hFcVTAf3Jd0

Comment: it's a hack and I think google won't allow this... but maybe i'll give it a try.

Comment: is there any other ad sdk with banner supporting parental gate or something to make this possible? I've tried leadbolt and revmob, but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: i didn't find any either. if you find. please share!

Comment: Still open in 2022 :( I found https://github.com/Kidoz-SDK/KIDOZ_ADMOB_iOS_ADAPTER Kidoz has a built-in parental gate, but I'm not sure if or how it works together with AdMob.